# If $\{B_{i} : i\in N\}$ is a denumerable family of pairwise disjoint distinct finite sets, then $\bigcup_{i\in N} B_{i}$ is denumerable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

So for this proof I'm thinking of creating a bijection from N to $\bigcup_{i\in N}  B_{i}$ , but I'm not sure how I should go about doing this. I thought about listing out a couple of sets from $\{B_{i} : i\in N\}$, and then listing a countable number of elements in each set and showing the bijection that way. Although that doesn't seem like the right way. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is also true when all $B_i$ are infinite.

For every $i \in B_i$ pick a distinct prime $p_i \in \mathbb{N}$. This can be done as there are infinitely many primes.

If $B_i = \{b_{i,n}: n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ (or finite). Then every $x \in \cup_i B_i$ has a unique representation as $b_{i,j}$ (because the sets are pairwise disjoint) and we map this to $(p_i)^j$. Then $f$ is an injection from $\cup_i B_i$ into $\mathbb{N}$. So the union is countable.